# Ising's model and conditional probabilities

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

I am trying to understand how the conditional probabilities of an Ising model having the following joint probability is given by a logistic regression model, as shown in the joint image. I'm more than confuse, could someone show me how?

There's not much documentation about it online, ughh!

[image]

Comment: I am surprised that you did not find much about the Ising model since this is the most commonly studied random field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the joint distribution
$$p(x|\theta)\propto\exp\left\{
\sum_i \theta_{ii} x_i + \sum_{i\sim j}\theta_{ij}x_ix_j
\right\}\tag{1}$$
(which is incorrectly involving a transpose ${\sf T}$ sign in the screen copy), the conditional distribution of component $k$ is
$$p(x_k|x_{-k},\theta)\propto p(x|\theta)$$
Hence picking only terms involving $x_k$ in (1) leads to
$$p(x_k|x_{-k},\theta)\propto\exp\left\{
\theta_{kk}x_k+\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_jx_k\right\}\tag{2}$$
If $x_k\in\{-1,1\}$,
$$\mathbb P(X_k=1|x_{-k},\theta)\propto\exp\left\{
\theta_{kk}+\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_j\right\}$$
and
$$\mathbb P(X_k=-1|x_{-k},\theta)\propto\exp\left\{
-\theta_{kk}-\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_j\right\}$$
hence
$$\mathbb P(X_k=1|x_{-k},\theta)=\exp\left\{
2\theta_{kk}+2\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_j\right\}
{\Huge/} 1+\exp\left\{
2\theta_{kk}+2\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_j\right\}$$
and
$$\mathbb P(X_k=1|x_{-k},\theta)=\exp\left\{
-2\theta_{kk}-2\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_j\right\}
{\Huge/} 1+\exp\left\{
-2\theta_{kk}-2\sum_{j\sim k}\theta_{jk}x_j\right\}$$